# Story about a character named Sargon who sequesters beautiful women in his trapezoidal castle

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

My brother wants to reread a science fiction short story from the 1960s or before:

A character named Sargon (does not appear in the story) sequesters maddeningly beautiful women in his truncated pyramid-shaped castle on another planet. The protagonist catches a glimpse of the inside, seeing at least one of these women. He pines for her and goes mad. My brother remembers wet streets and a lattice-work.

Comment: @user14111 short story, again, 1960s or before; science fiction; on another planet...protagonist, who may be earthborn, sees the women through a lattice work and does go mad...I know it isnt much to go on, and that it sounds really silly but that is what he has.

Comment: No need to apologize for your brother's taste in literature (which we, who are answering your questions, share). "The Helping Hand" is vintage Poul Anderson and was nominated for a Retro Hugo Award. C. L. Moore, the author of "Black Thirst", was the greatest female writer of fantasy and sci-fi. I'm waiting to find out what SF  classic your brother wants to reread next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be ['Black Thirst'](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45450)- a [Northwest Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwest_Smith) story by [C. L. Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._L._Moore).
A creature has been breeding beautiful women, refining them until the very sight of them can drive a man mad. He then consumes their life-force.